# How to retrieve the recipients email address from Laravel's Mail MessageSending event?

Tags: php, laravel, email, events, swiftmailer

As you may know, Laravel fires the [MessageSending](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#events) event when it's about to send an email message. I have added a Listener which listens for this specific event.

Unfortunately I'm unable to determine the recipient email address inside the Listener's handle method. The only argument I can get is the Swift Mailer message.

Do you know a way I could retrieve the recipients email address inside the Listener's handle method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call **getTo()** on the **Swift_Message** object to get a list of addresses the message will be sent to:

```
$message = $event->message;
$addresses = $message->getTo();
```

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, I'd like to point out this doesn't include CC and BCC. Just found this out after receiving a barrage of exceptions because getTo() was coming back null for some mass-mailers.

Answer (score 3):

The `->getTo()` method works differently in Laravel 9 now.

To simply get a list of email addresses sent to:

```
    public function handle($event)
    {
        $emails = collect($event->message->getTo())
            ->map(fn ($item) => $item->getAddress());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm with Laravel 10!